# Combine pAjax with assets loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, preloader

I'm using ajax to load a new page when user clicks a link on a page, and using HTML history push state for changing title, no problem there. There is a "loading bar" on top so user knows something is going on.

What I'd like to achieve is to replace a page once all assets from ajax loaded page are loaded, now on .done() I'm replacing only html string that's returned.

Site is image-heavy so I'm forced to:
a) load page with ajax (which is fairly quick)
b) when html is replaced, I need to show new "preloader" to actually load all assets

I would like to avoid doing b) thing.

Code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "urltoload.html",
    context: document.body
}).done(function(data) {
    var newDoc = document.open("text/html", "replace");
    newDoc.write(data);
    newDoc.close();
});
```

I am replacing full page (including scripts), as loaded page is full of assets (large images), I'm using this great tool [waitForImages](https://github.com/alexanderdickson/waitForImages) for loading all assets before really showing a page.

So first I load page with ajax, then when page is replaced I load images to show page. I would like to merge it onto one loading.

Comment: Please post your code as a snippet.

Comment: Added small snipper and more details.

Answer (score 0):

Append this to to your index.html page in body tag.

```
<body onload="loadcontent()">
```

And this to js part (Replace "YourContentFileUrl.html" in the below code with the file url to be fetched via ajax request):

```
function loadcontent() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
       document.open();
    document.write(xhttp.responseText);
    document.close(); 
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "YourContentFileUrl.html", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
```